# Need exactly one month in custom of daterangepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, date-range, daterangepicker, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I've specified the `datelimit as  dateLimit: { months : 1 }` in daterangepicker configuration.
When we click custom range and select dates, it is selecting 1 date plus one month.

Let's say if i open the `datepicker` now then it shows me the range until `05/08/2016`. But i want to see `04/08/2016`.

I want it to select exact one month. I've searched docs in http://www.daterangepicker.com/ but I'm not able to find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can check:

```
    $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
    startDate: start,
    endDate: end,
    ranges: {
       'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
       'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
       'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
       'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), 
     moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
    },
    "dateLimit": {
            "month": 1
        },
 }, cb);
```